# Upload to S3 failed with the following error: Access Denied - CodeStarConnections

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline

I am building a CI/CD pipeline using AWS Codepipeline, the repository source is on bitbucket and I used the AWS-Codestarconnections to create a connection between the bitbucket repository and the pipeline.

The pipeline details are below:

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "test_pipeline",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountId>:role/PipelineServiceRole",
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "tadadadada-artifact"
        },
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeStarSourceConnection",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "BranchName": "dev",
                            "ConnectionArn": "arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-2:<AccountId>:connection/4ca7b1cf-2917-4fda-b681-c5239944eb33",
                            "FullRepositoryId": "<username>/repository_name",
                            "OutputArtifactFormat": "CODE_ZIP"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [],
                        "region": "us-east-2",
                        "namespace": "SourceVariables"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Build",
                "actions": [
                    {
                      ....
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": 1
    },
    "metadata": {
        "pipelineArn": "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-2:<AccountId>:test_pipeline",
        "created": 1611669087.267,
        "updated": 1611669087.267
    }
}
```

The PipelineServiceRole + that policy attached to it are:

**Service Role**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Policy**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IamPassRolePolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "iam:PassRole"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEqualsIfExists": {
          "iam:PassedToService": [
            "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
            "ec2.amazonaws.com",
            "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "CodeBuildPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
        "codebuild:StartBuild"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "S3AccessPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ECRAccessPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:DescribeImages"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "CodeStarConnectionsAccessPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "codestar-connections:UseConnection"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The source stage fails with an error :

```
[Bitbucket] Upload to S3 failed with the following error: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 085999D90C19E650; S3 Extended Request ID: gJ6l08+cX3U6i2Vj0+fW7PiqA/UzM6ZGCfyECmWb+Jit4Knu+gi/L4y3F24uqkFWUfGy9tZo0VE=; Proxy: null) (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null) (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
```

The error message lacks details, I am not sure which service is trying to access s3, shouldn't it be code-pipeline (which in this case has PutObject permission)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Resolved this by changing the OutputArtifactFormat from `"OutputArtifactFormat": "CODE_ZIP"` to  `"OutputArtifactFormat": "CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF"`.

**CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF** - from the console description is a Full clone, in which case
AWS CodePipeline passes metadata about the repository that allows subsequent actions to do a full git clone. Only supported for AWS CodeBuild actions.
The "CODE_ZIP" option does not include the git metadata about the repository

Comment: A thousand thank you's! I'm using the AWS CDK and this led me to solve the same problem using:
```new codepipeline_actions.BitBucketSourceAction({ ..., codeBuildCloneOutput: true })```

Comment: If you're upgrading an older existing Code Pipeline to the GitHub V2 access, the step-two after selecting the above option is to add UseConnection permission to the Code Build role, which is different from the role used in the Source step

Answer (score 11):

This issue appears to be related to a recent change in the CDK's default IAM Role for the BitBucketSourceAction.

I found that by adding the "s3:PutObjectAcl" action to the list I was able to successfully integrate the BitBucketSourecAction (for GitHub version 2 connection). Note: this did not require:

- Changing the OutputArtifactFormat from `"OutputArtifactFormat": "CODE_ZIP"` to `"OutputArtifactFormat": "CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF"`, or,
- S3-full-access "s3:*"

As detailed in [this CDK issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10632), I was using the BitBucketSourceAction to integrate with a GitHub repository. I got the following error when the CodePipeline first attempted the GitHub (Version2) action:

```
[GitHub] Upload to S3 failed with the following error: Access Denied
```

On a previous pipeline I released with the BitBucketSourceAction the "s3:PutObject*" wildcarded action was included in the synthesized template. On reviewing the IAM role generated during my latest cdk deployment (using version 1.91.0) the BitBucketSourceAction only had the "s3:PutObject" action (i.e. not wildcarded). This excludes the "s3:PutObjectAcl" action which seems to be required to upload the source repository from GitHub to S3 and free it up for use further along in the pipeline.

Comment: This worked for me i.e. adding just "s3:PutObjectAcl" action permission to the role policy associated to the Pipeline Bucket Store, in addition to "s3:GetObjet" and "s3:PutObject"

Answer (score 9):

Adding the `s3:PutObjectAcl` action permission to the role policy associated with the Pipeline Bucket Store worked for me.

I had to add the following permissions:

- `s3:GetObject`
- `s3:GetObjectVersion`
- `s3:PutObject`
- `s3:GetBucketVersioning`
- `s3:PutObjectAcl`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Use markdown to properly format your post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using GitHub.

`[GitHub] Upload to S3 failed with the following error: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: foo; S3 Extended Request ID: bar; Proxy: null)`

But in the artifact store S3 bucket, object was updated.

So I changed s3 service policy to full access.

```
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetObjectVersion",
      "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
```

↓

```
      "s3:*",
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem today and idk why this fixed it but the policy attached to the `PipelineGithubRole` had 2 s3 statements, one contained just List* action and the other contained all the Read & Put actions, so I just moved them into a single statement and it started working.